# typedef struct default initialization

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

How's possible to make default initialization for structs?

I'm trying to make default initialization for my struct but I get this error:

```
error: request for member 'type' in '((CCatManager::cat_shop_item*)this)->CCatManager::cat_shop_item::catAttr', which is of non-class type 'TCategoryAttribute [0]'
..........................
```

Here is my codes:

```
enum EMisc
{
    CAT_MAX_NUM = 8,
};

typedef struct TCategoryAttribute
{
    BYTE    type;
    short   value;
} TCategoryAttribute;

typedef struct category_items
{
    long    price;
    DWORD   order;

    TCategoryAttribute    catAttr[CAT_MAX_NUM];

    category_items()
    {
        price = 0;
        order = 0;

        catAttr.type[0] = 0;
        .....
        catAttr.type[7] = 0;

        catAttr.value[0] = 0;
        .....
        catAttr.value[7] = 0;
    }
} CATEGORY_ITEMS;
```

"price" and "order" are okay, they work but TCategoryAttribute doesn't work...

I'm really confused... thanks in advance, and I hope the question is right.

---

It's solved, thanks to @Michael.

Comment: Did you mean `catAttr[0].type = ...` etc?

Comment: Btw, the largest index you should use for an array of length 3 is 2.

Comment: Are you working in C or C++?

Comment: C is a different language! Don't add C tag for C++ questions (and vice versa).

Comment: I'm sorry I'll remove it.

Comment: @Michael I'm updated the question check again please.

Comment: please mark the exact line where compiler places the error

Comment: @Michael, I'm so stupid, thank you very much, it works now. That was extraordinary stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `type` isn't an array, rather, `catAttr` is. Secondly, there are 3 of them you declared, hence you third item is at index 2. remember, you count from 0. So change this portion of your code to:

```
category_items()
    {
        price = 0;
        order = 0;

        catAttr[0].type = 0;
        catAttr[1].type = 0;
        catAttr[2].type = 0;
        //catAttr[3].type = 0; //you can't hit [3]

        catAttr[0].value = 0;
        catAttr[1].value = 0;
        catAttr[2].value = 0;
        //catAttr.value[3] = 0;
    }
```

See full code that compiles (and works) here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abda47415ebb9938

BTW, that `typedef` is redundant. Just do this instead...

```
struct TCategoryAttribute
{
    BYTE    type;
    short   value;
};
```

Comment: It compiles here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abda47415ebb9938 . What compiler are you using and what are your compiler flags?

Comment: catAttr.type[0] = 0; -> catAttr[0].type = 0; it works now, thank you.